# Docker echo environment variable

Tags: docker

I'm trying to write a little docker file that sets a User and just echos the current user as a little example to prove to myself it is working. I've tried a number of variants and couldn't find much help in the documentation.

```
FROM ubuntu
USER daemon
# ENTRYPOINT ["echo", "$USER"]
# just gives "$USER"
# ENTRYPOINT ["echo", "-e", "${USER}"]
# just gives "$USER"
# ENTRYPOINT echo $USER
# gives empty string
# ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/echo", "$USER"]
# just gives "$USER"
```

I'm running `docker build .` on the dockerfile and then running `docker run <image-id>` and getting the results

Expected result is `daemon`, or without the `USER daemon` line, I expect `root`. Probably a really simple answer.

Comment: I get the same behaviour during a Docker Build when I add an "echo" to a RUN command - it doesn't resolve the variable but simply prints it out as reported above.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is the expected behavior, as weird as it seems!

When `ENTRYPOINT` is a list (as in `ENTRYPOINT ["echo", "$USER"]`), it is used as-is, without further parsing or interpretation. So `$USER` remains `$USER`, because there is no shell involved in the process to replace it with the value of the `USER` environment variable.

Now, when `ENTRYPOINT` is a string (as in `ENTRYPOINT echo $USER`), what is actually executed is `sh -c "echo $USER"`, and `$USER` is replaced with the value of the environment variable (as you would expect).

However, the environment variable `USER` is not set by default. It is set by the login process; and when you just run `sh -c ...` the login process is not involved.

Compare the environment when running `docker run -t -i ubuntu bash` and `docker run -t -i ubuntu login -f root`. In the former case, you will get a very basic environment; in the latter case, you will get the complete environment that you are used to (including `USER`variable).

Answer (score 4):

Couldn't you set, in the Dockerfile, the `ENV` command to a default value, and then, when run-ning a container, use the `-e, --env` dictionary to override what would be interpreted by the:

```
ENTRYPOINT echo $SOMEENVVAR
```

form of ENTRYPOINT?

Answer (score 3):

I think there´s a series of issues here.

when I

```
docker run -i -t ubuntu /bin/bash
echo $USER
set
```

I don´t see $USER set at all - whoami does report daemon though.

additionally, I have the suspicion (but have not looked at the code yet) that ENV vars in the Dockerfile are escaped, to avoid their use (many people assume that they can export host variables to the built container, but this is something that the docker guys would like to avoid)