# Pass an environment variable to Docker

Tags: docker

Here is a particular operation everyone can try:

```
docker run --env TEST='xxx' ubuntu:14.04 /bin/echo $TEST
```

That returns an empty string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker echo environment variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896767/docker-echo-environment-variable)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason why echoing isn't working is that the `$TEST` environment variable is substituted on your host side. To postpone the substitution to container side, wrap the echo command with single quotes:

```
docker run --env TEST='xxx' ubuntu:14.04 sh -c 'echo $TEST'
```

Answer (score 5):

You're substituting TEST in your bash instead of your container.
Try this command to make sure your variable is passed correctly:

```
docker run --env TEST='xxx' ubuntu:14.04 /usr/bin/env
```